# Portion render when this.state update?

Tags: reactjs

```
function AnotherComponent() {
  console.log('AnotherComponent loading....');
  return (
    <p>2333</p>
  );
}
class ExampleComponent extends React.Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {
      val: 0,
    };
    setInterval(() => { this.setState({ val: this.state.val+1 }); }, 1000);
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <AnotherComponent />
      <p>test</p>
      <p id='counter'>{this.state.val}</p>
    );
  }
}
```

This is a simple react page. When I running it, I suprised and find many 'AnotherComponent loading....' in console.I think whole ExampleComponent is re-rendered when state change.
In my project, AnotherComponent is a login status monitor. Obviously, I don't need to re-render it when ExampleComponent's state change.
How can I only re-render p[id=counter] when state change?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is why [`React.memo`](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-api.html#reactmemo) is available. If a child component is unnecessarily rerendering when parent rerenders, you can wrap the child in `React.memo`.

```
const AnotherComponent = React.memo(() {
  console.log('AnotherComponent loading....');
  return (
    <p>2333</p>
  );
});
```